# How to override the description method for an object and print it out?

Tags: objective-c, nslog, nsobject

I need to override the `description` method to return the internal state of the object (in other words, dump all the values into a single line of text).

In my Model(Class) I have

Homework.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Homework : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *className;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *assignmentTitle;

@end
```

Homework.m

```
-(NSString *)description
{
return [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@, %@", self.className, self.assignmentTitle];
}
```

I created an object in my `ViewController`

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) Homework *homeworkAssignment;
```

And I try to print it like this

```
  NSLog(self.homeworkAssignment.description);
```

But it doesn't seem to work, the output prints out a comma ",". Am I formatting the `NSLog` wrong?  Did I override the method correctly?  This is my first app (besides "Hello World").

Comment: "Doesn't seem to work" - what does it do instead?

Comment: The output prints out a comma  ,

Comment: Then most likely `self.className` and `self.assignmentTitle` both contain empty strings.

Comment: Would it print (null) if the string was empty?

Comment: No, that's if it's `nil`. It prints nothing if it's an empty string. Where do you assign to the `className` and `assignmentTitle` properties?

Comment: @rmaddy Your right that was the only problem, I didn't realize the strings were empty because I expected to see (null) if they were.  I assigned values and it works fine.  If you wana put that as an answer Ill choose it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code all appears correct with regard to the implementation of `description` and the logging. Since the output only shows a comma it means that your two property both contain empty strings. If they were `nil` the string format would display them as `(null)`.

There is a difference between a `nil` pointer and a reference to the empty string (`@""`).

Comment: It works now, but I am getting a warning when I do  NSLog(self.homeworkAssignment.description);
That says (Format string is not a string literal: potentially insecure).  Do you know how I could get rid of this?

Comment: Change your `NSLog` to the way "Ticko" has it in their answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine, you can even just NSLog like this :

```
NSLog(@"%@", self.homeworkAssignment);
```

which returns

```
2013-09-29 23:56:50.375 test[2769:a0b] (null), (null)
```

Try assigning values to your className and assignmentTitle, so it wont return null :)

Comment: Read the question - it doesn't return `(null)`.

Comment: Well i copied/pasted his code and tried it a fresh new project, that's what it returned to me

Comment: But it is not what the OP was getting. The difference is that you never set any values for the two properties (hence the `(null)` output) while the OP had set them to empty strings (which is why he just has a comma and nothing else).